# Find $x+y+z$ from the equation

Tags: number-theory

In the equation

$$\dfrac{37}{13}=2+\dfrac{1}{x+\dfrac{1}{y+\dfrac 1z}}$$

find the value of $x+y+z$

How can I know the value of three variables while there is only one equation?

Comment: $x,y,z$ are positive integers, the equation is basically the [continued fraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction) representation of $\frac{37}{13}$. So $x = \left\lfloor\frac{1}{37/13 - 2}\right\rfloor = 1$, $y$ and $z$ can be computed in similar manner.

Comment: So basically, you find x, y and z by assuming that they must be integers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\frac{26+11}{13}=2+\frac{1}{\frac{13}{11}}=2+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{\frac{11}{2}}}=2+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{5+\frac{1}{2}}}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{37}{13}=2+\frac{11}{13}=2+\frac{1}{\frac{13}{11}}=2+\frac{1}{1+\frac{2}{11}}=...$$
Do you see how to continue?